# How to write Fortify custom rules language specific?

Tags: java, fortify

I'm creating some customs rules using Fortify but I wonder if there is any way to customise that rules so they can be language specific.

The reason for that is to be able to give custom descriptions  in Java and in .NET about SQL injection for instance and Custom references so they can be language specific.

It seems like Fortify maps custom rules by category,but the issue comes when we have two packages , one for .NET and other for Java and both of them exposes a category called Cross-Site Scripting.

Do you guys know how to make this rules language-specific?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the language attribute of the Rule like here:

```
<StructuralRule formatVersion="3.8" language="dotnet">
                <RuleID>1537A69A-F7EA-4D14-9F8F-0CC17806780A</RuleID>
                <VulnKingdom>Input Validation and Representation</VulnKingdom>
                <VulnCategory>SQL Injection</VulnCategory>
                <DefaultSeverity>2.0</DefaultSeverity>
                <Description></Description>
                <Predicate><![CDATA[
                    FunctionCall fc: fc.function is [Function f: f.name == "set_CommandText" and 
                                                                 f.enclosingClass.supers contains [Class c: c.name == "System.Data.IDbCommand"]] and
                                     not fc.enclosingFunction contains [FunctionCall call: call.function is 
                                                    [Function f1: f1.name == "set_CommandType" and
                                                                  f1.enclosingClass.supers contains [Class c1: c1.name == "System.Data.IDbCommand"]] and
                                                                        call.arguments[0].constantValue == 4]
                ]]></Predicate>
</StructuralRule>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. So by adding the language attribute (dotnet) will this custom Rule just be displayed when a SQL Injection flaw is found in any .Net project?.

Comment: Also it seems like I'm using an updated version of the rules 3.16 . And even when I've specified the language key to use java, this rule is displayed when a C# project is scaned. Do you know what might be wrong here?  ----  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RulePack xmlns="xmlns://www.fortifysoftware.com/schema/rules">
 <RulePackID>160F7B5A-85D0-4954-97D5-35C3F0285057</RulePackID>
 <SKU></SKU>
 <Name>TestM</Name>
 <Version>1.0</Version>
 <Language>java</Language>
 <Description>
 Custom Rule
 </Description> 
 <Rules version = "3.16">