# Enabling pmd kind of analysis in fortify

Tags: fortify

We are running fortify to check security vulnerabilities and sonar for code cleanup.

I would like to know if we can enable static code analysis in fortify and get rid of sonar/pmd/findbugs etc.

I have a java project which will be checked for security vulnerabilities using fortify sca. I also use sonar for code quality and cleanup.

Someone said me that I can configure sonar kind of rules in fortify so that I can avoid sonar and save the build time.

Basically I want to configure sonar rule set in fortify. So that fortify checks the security vulnerabilities and code quality and cleanup.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You question is rather unclear, what are you trying to achieve ? which kind of code are you analysing ? do you want to get rid of SonarQube alltogether ? do you want to customize the checks ? Please edit your question to make clear what you are trying to achieve regarding to what you are doing.

Comment: @benzonico Updated the original post

Comment: Ok so this is a question for someone knowing fortify rather than sonarqube.

Answer (score 3):

The default Fortify ruleset includes many "sonar-like" style checks.  For example, Null Dereference or Poor Exception Handling. It does not have ALL of the Sonar checks, but you could make them yourself using Custom Rules.

See this post for an example:

[How to write Fortify custom rules language specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521120/how-to-write-fortify-custom-rules-language-specific)

And here is one based on Spring MVC:

http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2013/12/2/building-fortify-custom-rules-for-spring-mvc.html

Fortify also includes findbugs, and also contributes to the findbugs OSS code.

Comment: I already saw the stackoverflow post to write custom rules. I tried and I was not able to write one. It would be helpful if you can write a sample rule which checks if all method arguments are declared final or not. And if would be helpful if you provide me links to any fortify custom rules documentation. I tried but I did not find any links related to api calls, syntaxes etc

Comment: can you please point me to some link which lists all sonar-like style checks which fortify supports by default